# Short story in which time slips and the passenger pigeon reappears in North America

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I read a sci-fi short story in an anthology.

The story featured a college professor who realized time was unravelling when the skies darkened with passenger pigeons.

This was in the early seventies and the stories were mind-blowing for a ten-year-old.

Comment: First asked about [ten years ago](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48889/a-story-about-reality-breaking-down-as-timelines-cross-in-increasing-numbers)!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 we don't close story id questions as duplicates unless the OP agrees that their question is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: Don, if the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can "accept" the answer of your choice by clicking on the check mark next to it. On the other hand, if "Sidewise in Time" is *not* the story you were looking for, you should post a comment to that effect (and maybe tell us how it differs from your story) and we will continue the search.

Answer (score 11):

["Sidewise in Time"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47101), a novella by [Murray Leinster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murray_Leinster) which was also the answer to the question [A story about reality breaking down as timelines cross in increasing numbers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48889); first published in [*Astounding Stories*, June 1934](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57529+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v13n04_1934-06/page/n11/mode/2up). You may have read it in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?47101).

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidewise_in_Time) plot summary:

> Professor Minott is a mathematician at Robinson College in Fredericksburg, Virginia who has determined that an apocalyptic cataclysm is fast approaching that could destroy the entire universe. The cataclysm manifests itself on June 5, 1935 (one year in the future of the story's original publication) when sections of the Earth's surface begin changing places with their counterparts in alternate timelines. A Roman legion from a timeline where the Roman Empire never fell appears on the outskirts of St. Louis, Missouri. Viking longships from a timeline where the Vikings settled North America raid a seaport in Massachusetts. A traveling salesman from Louisville, Kentucky, whose van bears a commercial logo including Uncle Sam with the Stars and Stripes, finds himself in trouble with the law when he travels into an area where the South won the American Civil War. A ferry approaching San Francisco finds the flag of Tsarist Russia flying from a grim fortress dominating the city.

Here is the part about the passenger pigeons:

> The sky was dark with birds above him. A flock four miles wide and three miles long made lights necessary in the village. The air was filled with the sound of wings. The passenger pigeon had returned to a continent from which it had been absent for almost fifty years.

Answer (score 8):

[Sidewise in Time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidewise_in_Time) by Murray Leinster, I think, which features a professor who leads a group of students through a series of transitions between alternate histories.

This article mentions the [pigeons](https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/14587)

> In Murray Leinster's Sidewise in Time where parts of alternative
> histories shift into our own reality a boy asks his grandfather what
> the millions of birds flying over them are and after shooting a few
> the grandfather discovers them to be the extinct Passenger Pigeon. The
> flock is said to be so large that its flight overhead lasts for hours.
> At the end of the short story a billion and a half of the birds remain
> in North America.

It's been collected many [times](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47101) - you may have read it in *Before the Golden Age*

Answer (score 7):

In the story *[Sidewise in Time](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47101)* by Murray Leinster time unravels and passenger pigeons appear.

> The size of each flock was to be measured not in feet or yards, but in miles of front.
>
> ...
>
> "It's a wild pigeon! What they used to call passenger pigeons! Back in '78 there were these birds by billions."

When the time oscillations stop, some segments of the alternate realities remain. One of them is the passenger pigeons.

There is a professor in the story, but he is not the one who sees the passenger pigeons.